# In which order should I join my two tables?

Tags: sql, join, key

I have the following tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "image_e"
(
    "id"    int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "title" varchar(32),
    "alt"   varchar(16)  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")

)   ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "image_version_e"
(
    "id"      int unsigned      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "imageId" int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    "format"  varchar(4)        NOT NULL,
    "size"    int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    "width"   smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
    "height"  smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
    "src"     varchar(64)       NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")

)   ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE "image_version_e"
    ADD UNIQUE KEY ("imageId", "format", "width", "height"),
    ADD UNIQUE KEY ("src");
```

I would like to join these to table to link the image row with it's associated image version row(s). Does it really matter in which order I join them ? What is the difference if I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM image_e
LEFT JOIN image_version_e
    ON image_version_e.imageId = image_e.id
```

Instead of :

```
SELECT *
FROM image_version_e
LEFT JOIN image_e
    ON image_e.id = image_version_e.id
```

Comment: For `OUTER JOINS` (`LEFT` and `RIGHT` in particular) the order matters significantly.

Comment: If you post some *sample* data and the *expected* result, you will get a more precise answer.

Comment: I don't really need a query, i just wanted to know what using one of these queries rather than the other one involves.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `left join`s so there is a big difference between the two queries.

The first keeps all records in `image_e` along with matching records in `image_version_e`.

The second keeps all records in `image_version_e` along with matching record sin `image_e`.

Of these two, you should use the one that is semantically correct for your application.

It is quite possible that you really want an `inner join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM image_e inner join
     image_version_e
     ON image_version_e.imageId = image_e.id;
```

With an inner join, the join order shouldn't make a difference (the compiler will choose what it considers to be the best order).